# Android spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Я получаю значение для spinner из базы данных на сервере и храню его в ArrayList:

```
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                if (jsonArray != null) {

                   //JSONArray userDetails = jsonObj.getJSONArray("child_name");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject)jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        NameChild cat = new NameChild(catObj.getString("id"), catObj.getString("name"));
                        namesList.add(cat);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

После этого я загружает одно из полученных значений в spinner:

```
 List <String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < namesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(namesList.get(i).getName());

    }

    spinnerview = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: 
как мне получить id выбранного значения с spinner, которое было загружено вместе с ним с сервера?

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо отображать не строки в адаптере, но объекты ваших данных. Для этого надо:

1. Указать адаптеру тип отображаемых данных при его создании, т.е. заменить `String` на `NameChild` так:

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<NameChild>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, namesList);
```

2. Переопределить `toString()` метод в вашем объекте данных для того, чтобы спиннер отображал нужное. В вашем случае - пусть метод возвращает `NameChild#getName()` так:

```
public class NameChild {

    //тут существующие методы класса

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```